# How to display x509certifcate in android app

Tags: android, web-services, x509certificate2

I use spongycastle. I downloaded byte array certificate from webservice in android app (I think is base64 byte array) and want to display it on screen. I wrote below code but It does not work and c variable is null. 
in addition I don't know how to display it on screen.

```
  SoapObject result = (SoapObject)envelope.bodyIn;           

                   if(result != null)
                    {
                        Object cert= result.getProperty(0);   
                        InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(cert.toString().getBytes());
                        CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509","BC");
                        java.security.cert.Certificate c = cf.generateCertificate(is);
                        X509Certificate t = (X509Certificate) c;
                        System.out.println("ca=" + t.getSubjectDN());


                   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably `cert.toString().getBytes()` is the problem. A certificate is encoded in binary format. To build it you need a byte array, not a string converted to bytes.

Ensure in which format are you receiving the certificate in order to transform it into binary. If you think that the certificate is encoded in base64, decode it in this way

```
 byte[] data = Base64.decode(base64, Base64.DEFAULT);
```

Note also the Java Security API Provider name for SpongyCastle is `SC` rather than `BC`

To display a text you need  for example to set the contento of a TextView inside an Activity or Fragment. I suggest you to get a tutorial first

Comment: Thank you very much. I wrote my code "InputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(cert.toString(), Base64.DEFAULT));" and It is ok.  But  I had error with " SC" and I used "BC".  I want to display x509certificate file on screen and Textview is used for display a text.Can you help me?

Comment: Check adding this simple example to your app https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-hello-world-example/

Comment: Thanks in advance pedrofb but I want to load x509certificate file on screen  and user can view general tab,Detailtab and certificate path tab in x509 certificate file like open google certificate in android app. but I want to open my certificate on screen rather than google certificate

Comment: sorry, i had misunderstood. With`X509Certificate` you can extracto most of these fields, but if you do not want to deal with asn1 for extensions, use the spongycastle API to parse the certificate. I can not provide you a full example. Look for specific examples in SO with 'bouncycastle' tag. The api is basically the same, but use spongycastle because in new versions of android 'bouncycastle' is removed

Comment: Thank you very much pedrofb

Comment: Excuse me pedrofb. I can't uderstand. I want to display a certificate on screen in order to the user can see general tab,detail tab. I don't want extract field from certificate. can I do it?

Comment: I see google certificate in my phone. I think it is a dialog and extracts certificate detail into it. I will do it too. thank you very much

Comment: if you are looking for a built in viewer like in Windows, there is no such thing in android. You need to generate your own activities to display the certificate fields, chain, etc. For example this one(opensource): https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.bitfire.cadroid